# Flexbox - having items on their own line but only 50% wide

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a form, similar to this layout:

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-child {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.flex-child:nth-child(-n+3) {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

.flex-child:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  /* hacks to force element onto next line below */
  /* margin-right: 1px; */
  /* or */
  /* flex-basis: 51% */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div style="background-color: #46DBFF;">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div style="background-color: rgb(55, 165, 192);">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div style="background-color: #46DBFF;">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div style="background-color: rgb(55, 165, 192);">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div style="background-color: #46DBFF;">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div style="background-color: rgb(55, 165, 192);">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is item 5 to sit under item 4 instead of next to it without any dodgy hacks

I can't change the html or the css too much but something in class .flex-child:nth-last-child(-n+3) would be ideal.

Is there a nice flex way to achieve this?

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: you already found some ways, they aren't good for you? if yes, why?

Answer (score 1):

You could change your flex-direction of your flex-parent to column and then change the width of the flex-child elements to 50%. That way it is not a dirty hack and you don't have to change too much.

```
.flex-parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-child:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    width: 50%;
}
```

(I removed all the unnecessary css definitons)

http://jsfiddle.net/1m8er2cx/

Best of luck!

Comment: yeah, i was thinking something like that, I should have included more info... further down the form i may need to have 2 or more items next to each other instead of stacked, like 3 DOB select boxes... how would i go about that? cheers!!

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle for that case? I am not sure I know what you mean

Comment: what i mean is, i need items 4,5,6 to sit on top of each other, like block level elements, the same as your fiddle... then i want 7,8,9 (Date of birth fields) to sit next to each other like inline elements, at 30% width say

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a hidden elemet use pseudo element then adjust the order:

```css
.flex-parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-child {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}

.flex-child:nth-child(-n+3) {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
}
.flex-child:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    order:2;
}
.flex-parent:after {
  content:"";
  width:1px;
  order:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-child">
        <div style="background-color: #46DBFF;">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child">
        <div style="background-color: rgb(55, 165, 192);">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child">
        <div style="background-color: #46DBFF;">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child">
        <div style="background-color: rgb(55, 165, 192);">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child">
        <div style="background-color: #46DBFF;">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child">
        <div style="background-color: rgb(55, 165, 192);">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```